# Python sqlAlchemy bulk update but non-serializable JSON attributes

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

I am trying to better understand how I can bulk update rows in sqlAlchemy using a Python function for each row that requires dumping results to `json` without having to iterate over them individually:

```
def do_something(x):
  return x.id + x.offset
```

```
table.update({Table.updated_field: do_something(Table)})
```

This is a simplification of what I am trying to accomplish except I get the error `TypeError: Object of type InstrumentedAttribute is not JSON serializable`.

Any thoughts on how to fix the issue here?

Comment: I am just trying to update a bulk of records without having to loop through them. I have a function that takes a json and searches for fields within that json.

Comment: However, I get InstrumentedError when I try doing an update like that one.

Comment: Where is the JSON? That's the thing you have to pass instead of `Table.id`.
You should have a JSON file or string with the things you want to update.

Comment: Yes, there is a json field. Call it `meta`

Comment: Updated question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you casting your Table Id to a json String? remove it and try.

Edit:

You can't call the same object in bulk, you can for example:

```
table.update({Table.updated_field: json.dumps(object_of_my_table variable._asdict())})
```

If you want update your column attribute with the whole object you will must loop and dump it in the update as:

```
for table in dbsession.query(Table):
    table.update_field = json.dumps(table._asdict())
    dbsession.add(table).
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer, but doing it through a loop will be very time consuming for 3.7 million rows of data.

Answer (score 1):

Without the requirement to serialise to JSON,

```py
session.query(Table).update({'updated_field': Table.id + Table.offset})
```

would work fine, performing all computations and updates in the database. However

```py
session.query(Table).update({'updated_field': json.dumps(Table.id + Table.offset)})
```

does not work, because it mixes Python-level operations (`json.dumps`) with database-level operations (add `id` and `offset` for all rows).

Fortunately, many RDBMS provide JSON functions ([SQLite](https://sqlite.org/json1.html), [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-functions/), [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html)) so that we can do the work solely in the database layer.  This is considerably more efficient that fetching data into the Python layer, mutating it, and writing it back to the database. Unfortunately, the available functions and their behaviours are not consistent across RDBMS.

The following script should work for SQLite, PostgreSQL and MaraiDB (and probably MySQL too). These assumptions are made:

- `id` and `offset` are both columns in the database table being updated
- both are integers, as is their sum
- the desired result is that their sum is written to a JSON column as an scalar

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB

urls = [
    'sqlite:///so73956014.db',
    'postgresql+psycopg2:///test',
    'mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost/test',
]

for url in urls:
    engine = sa.create_engine(url, echo=False, future=True)
    print(f'Checking {engine.dialect.name}')

    Base = orm.declarative_base()

    JSON = JSONB if engine.dialect.name == 'postgresql' else sa.JSON

    class Table(Base):
        __tablename__ = 't73956014'

        id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
        offset = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
        updated_field = sa.Column(JSON)

    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = orm.sessionmaker(engine, future=True)

    with Session.begin() as s:
        ts = [Table(offset=o * 10) for o in range(1, 4)]
        s.add_all(ts)

    # Use DB-specific function to serialise to JSON.
    if engine.dialect.name == 'postgresql':
        func = sa.func.to_jsonb
    else:
        func = sa.func.json_quote

    # MariaDB requires that argument to json_quote is character type.
    if engine.dialect.name in ['mysql', 'mariadb']:
        expr = sa.cast(Table.id + Table.offset, sa.Text)
    else:
        expr = Table.id + Table.offset

    with Session.begin() as s:
        s.query(Table).update(
            {Table.updated_field: func(expr)}
        )

    with Session() as s:
        ts = s.scalars(sa.select(Table))
        for t in ts:
            print(t.id, t.offset, t.updated_field)

    engine.dispose()
```

Output:

```
Checking sqlite
1 10 11
2 20 22
3 30 33
Checking postgresql
1 10 11
2 20 22
3 30 33
Checking mysql
1 10 11
2 20 22
3 30 33
```

Other functions can be used if the desired result is an object or array.  If updating an existing JSON column value the column my need to use the [Mutable](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/mutable.html) extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update millions of rows the best way from my experience is with Pandas and [bulk_update_mappings](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.bulk_update_mappings).

You can load data from the DB in bulk as a DataFrame with [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) by passing a query statement and your engine object.

```
import pandas as pd

query = session.query(Table)
table_data = pd.read_sql(query.statement, engine)
```

Note that `read_sql` has a `chunksize` parameter which causes it to return an iterator, so if the table is too large to fit in memory, you can throw this in a loop with however many rows your pc can handle at once:

```
for table_chunk in pd.read_sql(query.statement, engine, chunksize=1e6):
    ...
```

From there you can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to alter each column with any custom function you want:

```
table_data["column_1"] = table_data["column_1"].apply(do_something)
```

Then, converting the DataFrame to a dict with the `records` orientation puts it in  the appropriate format for `bulk_update_mappings`:

```
table_data = table_data.to_dict("records")
session.bulk_update_mappings(Table, table_data)
session.commit()
```

Additionally, if you need to perform a lot of json operations for your updates, I've used [orjson](https://pypi.org/project/orjson/) for updates like this in the past which also provides a notable speed improvement over the standard library's `json`.

Comment: Can we give a proper example of query.statement in this case? This looks promising.

Comment: It's just any query object from the sqlalchemy query API (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#query-api), like shown here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sqlalchemy-orm-query/